# Error (12006): Node instance "" instantiates undefined entity ""

Tags: verilog, quartus

I want to compile a CPU written in Verilog, but for some reason I can't. The source code is this [Github](https://github.com/ridecore/ridecore/tree/master/src/fpga). Only system.v received an error that clk_out was covered with capital letters, so I changed it to clk_out_lower. I changed it to clk_out_lower.
 Windows 10, Quartus 21.1.1, Verilog-2001.

```
Error (12006): Node instance "ibuf" instantiates undefined entity "IBUFGDS". 
Error (12006): Node instance "obuf" instantiates undefined entity "BUFG". 
Error (12006): Node instance "fbuf" instantiates undefined entity "BUFG". 
Error (12006): Node instance "mmcm" instantiates undefined entity "MMCME2_ADV". .
```

system.v

```
`default_nettype none
`include "define.v"

module CLKGEN_DCM(CLK_IN, CLK_OUT, LOCKED);
    input wire  CLK_IN;
    output wire CLK_OUT, LOCKED;

    wire clk_ibuf;
    wire clk_out_lower;
    wire clk0, clk0_fbuf;

    // input buffer
    IBUFG ibuf (.I(CLK_IN),
                .O(clk_ibuf));
    // output buffer
    BUFG  obuf (.I(clk_out_lower),
                .O(CLK_OUT));
    // feedback buffer
    BUFG  fbuf (.I(clk0),
                .O(clk0_fbuf));

    // dcm instantiation
    DCM_SP dcm (// input
                .CLKIN   (clk_ibuf),
                .RST     (1'b0),
                // output
                .CLKFX   (clk_out_lower),
                .LOCKED  (LOCKED),
                // feedback
                .CLK0    (clk0),
                .CLKFB   (clk0_fbuf), 
                // phase shift
                .PSEN    (1'b0),
                .PSINCDEC(1'b0),
                .PSCLK   (1'b0),
                // digital spread spectrum
                .DSSEN   (1'b0));

    defparam dcm.CLKIN_PERIOD   = `DCM_CLKIN_PERIOD;
    defparam dcm.CLKFX_MULTIPLY = `DCM_CLKFX_MULTIPLY;
    defparam dcm.CLKFX_DIVIDE   = `DCM_CLKFX_DIVIDE;
endmodule

/**************************************************************************************************/

module CLKGEN_MMCM(CLK_IN, CLK_OUT, LOCKED);
    input wire  CLK_IN;
    output wire CLK_OUT, LOCKED;

    wire clk_out_lower;
    wire clkfb, clkfb_fbuf;

    // output buffer
    BUFG  obuf (.I(clk_out_lower),
                .O(CLK_OUT));
    // feedback buffer
    BUFG  fbuf (.I(clkfb),
                .O(clkfb_fbuf));

    MMCME2_ADV mmcm (// input
                     .CLKIN1       (CLK_IN),
                     .CLKIN2       (1'b0),
                     .CLKINSEL     (1'b1),
                     .RST          (1'b0),
                     .PWRDWN       (1'b0),
                     // output
                     .CLKOUT0      (clk_out_lower),
                     .CLKOUT0B     (),
                     .CLKOUT1      (),
                     .CLKOUT1B     (),
                     .CLKOUT2      (),
                     .CLKOUT2B     (),
                     .CLKOUT3      (),
                     .CLKOUT3B     (),
                     .CLKOUT4      (),
                     .CLKOUT5      (),
                     .CLKOUT6      (),
                     .LOCKED       (LOCKED),
                     // feedback
                     .CLKFBOUT     (clkfb),
                     .CLKFBIN      (clkfb_fbuf),
                     .CLKFBOUTB    (),
                     // dynamic reconfiguration
                     .DADDR        (7'h0),
                     .DI           (16'h0),
                     .DWE          (1'b0),
                     .DEN          (1'b0),
                     .DCLK         (1'b0),
                     .DO           (),
                     .DRDY         (),
                     // phase shift
                     .PSCLK        (1'b0),
                     .PSEN         (1'b0),
                     .PSINCDEC     (1'b0),
                     .PSDONE       (),
                     // status
                     .CLKINSTOPPED (),
                     .CLKFBSTOPPED ());

    defparam mmcm.CLKIN1_PERIOD    = `MMCM_CLKIN1_PERIOD;
    defparam mmcm.CLKFBOUT_MULT_F  = `MMCM_VCO_MULTIPLY;
    defparam mmcm.DIVCLK_DIVIDE    = `MMCM_VCO_DIVIDE;
    defparam mmcm.CLKOUT0_DIVIDE_F = `MMCM_CLKOUT0_DIVIDE;
    defparam mmcm.CLKOUT1_DIVIDE   = `MMCM_CLKOUT1_DIVIDE;
endmodule

/**************************************************************************************************/

module RSTGEN(CLK, RST_X_I, RST_X_O);
    input wire  CLK, RST_X_I;
    output wire RST_X_O;

    reg [7:0] cnt;
    assign RST_X_O = cnt[7];

    always @(posedge CLK or negedge RST_X_I) begin
        if      (!RST_X_I) cnt <= 0;
        else if (~RST_X_O) cnt <= (cnt + 1'b1);
    end
endmodule

/**************************************************************************************************/

module GEN_DCM(CLK_I, RST_X_I, CLK_O, RST_X_O);
    input wire  CLK_I, RST_X_I;
    output wire CLK_O, RST_X_O;
    
    wire LOCKED;
    
    CLKGEN_DCM clkgen(.CLK_IN (CLK_I),
                      .CLK_OUT(CLK_O),
                      .LOCKED (LOCKED));
    RSTGEN     rstgen(.CLK    (CLK_O),
                      .RST_X_I(RST_X_I & LOCKED),
                      .RST_X_O(RST_X_O));
endmodule

module GEN_MMCM(CLK_I, RST_X_I, CLK_O, RST_X_O);
    input wire  CLK_I, RST_X_I;
    output wire CLK_O, RST_X_O;
    
    wire clk_ibuf;
    wire LOCKED;

    // input buffer
    IBUFG ibuf (.I(CLK_I),
                .O(clk_ibuf));

    CLKGEN_MMCM clkgen(.CLK_IN (clk_ibuf),
                       .CLK_OUT(CLK_O),
                       .LOCKED (LOCKED));
    RSTGEN      rstgen(.CLK    (CLK_O),
                       .RST_X_I(RST_X_I & LOCKED),
                       .RST_X_O(RST_X_O));
endmodule

module GEN_MMCM_DS(CLK_P, CLK_N, RST_X_I, CLK_O, RST_X_O);
    input wire  CLK_P, CLK_N, RST_X_I;
    output wire CLK_O, RST_X_O;

    wire clk_ibuf;
    wire LOCKED;

    // input buffer
    IBUFGDS ibuf (.I (CLK_P),
                  .IB(CLK_N),
                  .O (clk_ibuf));

    CLKGEN_MMCM clkgen(.CLK_IN (clk_ibuf),
                       .CLK_OUT(CLK_O),
                       .LOCKED (LOCKED));
    RSTGEN      rstgen(.CLK    (CLK_O),
                       .RST_X_I(RST_X_I & LOCKED),
                       .RST_X_O(RST_X_O));
endmodule

/**************************************************************************************************/
`default_nettype wire
/**************************************************************************************************/
```

The top entity is top.v. I checked IBUFGDS, etc. and found it only in this system.v.

Answer (score 1):

IBUFGDS,BUFG,MMCME2_ADV are Xilinx library primitives.

Altera/Intel tools do not understand what these are.

If this code is built in a Xilinx Vivado then a synthesis tool (Vivado) will natively understand what these are.

The code can be simulated using standard simulation tools (Modelsim,Incisive etc), however the Xilinx Unisim & Simprim libraries will need to be compiled as part of that simulation.
This is getting into vendor specific territory; example for Modelsim.
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60319/how-to-add-the-xilinx-library-to-modelsim

Check with the author about what tools he used, and what libraries he needed to compile, and how he did the compilation.  If he used Xilinx for simulation & synthesis it might all be native with nothing extra to do.

Behavioral models of these vendor models could be written for simulation.  You would need to do homework on exactly what each one of these does.

An equivalent behavioral model of MMCME2_ADV  will not work in Altera syntheses.  Its a complex IP built into the Xilinx hardware.  Its typical use is clock generation.

I looked at the linked github page found this regarding the target hardware & tools:

```
Our FPGA prototyping efforts have so far resulted in a prototype for Xilinx VC707 board. This prototype can operate at a clock frequency of 50MHz (Vivado 2015.2 is used for synthesizing and implementing the design).
```

Vivado 2015.2 was used for the github project you are trying to use.